# On the proof of the Hermitian functions being a basis of $L^2(R)$ space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Define $h_k(x) = H_k(x) e^{- x^2/2} $ where $H_k(x)$ is the k-th Hermitian polynomial.

Assuming already having shown that the $h_k(x)$ form an orthonormal system in $L^2(R)$ with the usual inner product how can one prove that they are a basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement @MartinArgerami's answer: although it is certainly traditional to invoke something like Weierstrass approximation (for polynomials on compacts) to know that Hermite polynomials times Gaussians are dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$, it is also possible to give a more structural argument that can apply in situations where a Stone-Weierstrass argument is much less clear. Namely, the functions $h_k$ of the question are eigenfunctions for the so-called quantum harmonic oscillator $-\Delta+x^2$ (studied by many people long before quantum theory, e.g., Hermite, Mehler (1868), and others). It is an interesting calculus exercise to show that the resolvent is compact (self-adjoint) (e.g., using Friedrichs' extension construction), and for general reasons this implies that the spectrum of the operator is the collection of inverses of the spectrum of the resolvent, in particular purely discrete.

Then the issue becomes to show that there are no *other* eigenfunctions than the $h_k$. At this point, the "ladder" or "raising/lowering" operators are relevant, looking at the factorization of $-\Delta+x^2$ via the "Dirac operator", in this case simply $i{\partial\over \partial x}$. One shows that *all* eigenfunctions are obtained by "raising" the bottom eigenfunction, $e^{-x^2/2}$, and these are exactly the $h_k$...

Answer (score 2):

You need to show that $\{h_k\}$ is total: that is,  $$\tag{1}\langle f,h_k\rangle=0,\ \ \  \text{ for all } k,\ \ \implies f=0.$$ Since the orthogonal of a set is the same as the orthogonal of the closure of a set, it is enough to show the above on a dense set. So now you have to show $(1)$ when $f$ is a polynomial times $e^{-x^2}$, or a characteristic function.

Comment: Well, minor issue that polynomials aren't in $L^2$, ... but this can be overcome. And then invoke Weierstrass. Also, more fancily, one might look at the spectral theory of $-\Delta+x^2$, which demonstrably has compact resolvent.

Comment: Good points, Paul, although I cannot really comment on the second approach.

Comment: @paulgarrett what is a good reference for learning more about spectral theory and compact resolvent? :)

Comment: @Monolite, Reed-and-Simon's "Methods of Math Phys" is a standard reference, though pricey and perhaps toooo encyclopedic. Peter Lax' book is very good. I have on-line notes on many aspects of this sort of issue, e.g., at http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/  Googling around will surely find you many more sets of notes on-line.

Comment: Also, section 9.8 in my book at http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/Book_28Aug2017.pdf does the $-\Delta+x^2$ example in detail, in a fairly free-standing form (that is, despite the fact that the larger goal of the book as about automorphic forms...)

Comment: Mister Argerami why is saying $\langle f,h_k\rangle=0,\ \ \  \text{ for all } k,\ \ \implies f=0.$  equivalent to the $h_k$ spanning $L^2(R)$?

Comment: By definition, a basis is a total orthonormal system. So the question is why an orthonormal basis span the Hilbert space. Suppose it doesn't: that means that the orthogonal of the span is nonzero; but this would allow you to find a vector orthonormal to the whole basis, a contradiction.